# Force system time to sync with NTP Android or iPhone

Tags: android, ios, ntp

In my apps, it's really important that the system time on an Android or iPhone device is as accurate and close to NTP time as possible. Sometimes this can be very off, despite having a cellular signal (here's an example: http://cl.ly/image/2m2W0C0G1r3b).

Is there a way on iPhone or Android to force the system time to sync with NTP to be as accurate as possible?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you cannot force syncing to NTP, in part because the device might not be using NTP for its time, instead using NITZ or values entered by the user.

You are welcome to use some SNTP client library to determine the time from an NTP server, for use within your own app.